# Nested objects, preventing "cannot get value of 'undefined'"

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have an object called John with many other nested objects inside and I am trying to access them following way

```
if (john.address.highstreet) {
    var highstreet = john.address.highstreet
}
```

but if address property is null, then I will get an error

```
unable to get property 'highstreet' of undefined
```

and my function execution stops

Is there a way of accessing nested properties without making many nested if statements like it's shown below:

```
if (john.address) {
    if (john.address.highstreet) {
        var highstreet = john.address.highstreet
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use something like lodash's [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get)

Answer (score 6):

The standard way would be

```
if (john.address && john.address.highstreet) {
    var highstreet = john.address.highstreet
}
```

If address is undefined then that is what will be returned.

Comment: thank you! That seems like the best way of doing it.

Comment: Note that this works because Javascript boolean operators are [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: indeed.  Hence why it is `&&` rather than just `&` - same convention as C

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a bit more clever way of accessing these properties. Something like `getPropertyByString("john.address.highstreet")`. This function could return `null` or undefined if the path can't be resolved.

As in [Alnitak's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/852866)

So your code could look just like this:

```
var highstreet = getPropertyByString("john.address.highstreet");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to use a try-catch-block.

```
try {
    var highstreet = john.address.highstreet;
} catch (err) {
    // do error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **hasOwnProperty** method to check for property

```
if(john.hasOwnProperty("address") && john.address.hasOwnProperty("highstreet"))
{
var highstreet = john.address.highstreet
}
```